# Add an SQLite database to an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I am trying to learn SQLite, and I am building an iPhone app. But I would like to add an SQLite database to my building app. I have got three tutorials, but I am not clear on that code.

How can I add an SQLite database to my building app? What would sample code look like?

Comment: Why dont you accept an answer, if indeed it has helped you?

Answer (score 20):

First of all you need to create your database.
From the command line create your db file.

```
sqlite3 mydb.db
```

Then create the tables within your database

```
CREATE TABLE tags (id int(5), name varchar(255), created_at datetime, updated_at datetime);
```

Repeat that for any tables that you want in your database.

Then you need to include the database file in your project. Add the existing database file to your project as you would any other existing file.

Next you will have to link in the framework to interact with the database. This can be found under you current iPhone SDK folder.

*/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.2.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib*

Finally you have to include the header file sqlite3.h from

*/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.2.sdk/usr/include/sqlite3.h*

It should now be possible to write code to access your sqlite database from within your iPhone application.

Comment: Note that, while creating a database on a desktop machine and then copying it into the iPhone app may be an expedient thing to do, it is not necessary.  You can create a database, initialize the schema, and initialize data from within the iPhone app.

Answer (score 12):

**There is lots of information on the web.**

Have you looked at the demo application? [SQLite Book List](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SQLiteBooks/index.html) This shows examples of common database functions under SQLite. This is effectively using the standard SQLite C APIs.

There are Objective C wrappers which may suite you more.
[EntropyDB](http://code.google.com/p/entropydb/), [SQLitePersistenceObjects](http://code.google.com/p/sqlitepersistentobjects/) and [FMDB](http://gusmueller.com/blog/archives/2008/06/new_home_for_fmdb.html).

I found this [Tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/) and this list of [resources](http://www.mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/) which may help.

Recently I've been using [an ORM SQLite.net](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/) It is the way to go for me but then I'm developing in MonoTouch C#.

Tony

Answer (score 6):

I'd also recommend looking at [FMDB](http://code.google.com/p/flycode/). It makes using SQLite slightly more Objective-C/Cocoa-like. It's not a full ORM wrapper or anything though; it just wraps the C API into something a bit more flavoursome.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlite.org/docs.html is a good place to start.

You might get more useful help if you are more specific about what you are trying to do, and what obstacles you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firefox, there's this [handy addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) that you can use to manage and create an SQLite database.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to link in the framework to interact with the database. This can be found under you current iPhone SDK folder.

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS2.2.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

CoreData should help, but I can't find it anywhere in the list of importable Frameworks.

You could take a peek at the iPhone examples, especially the [SQLite Book List](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SQLiteBooks/index.html) example.

Comment: CoreData isn't available on the iPhone.

Comment: CoreData is available with the SDK 3.00 beta.