# confused about from where to start

Tags: iphone, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone and SQLite introductory articles or tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395196/iphone-and-sqlite-introductory-articles-or-tutorials)

Sir,i am iphone trainee,just have finished with UIApplications of Iphone.
Now i want to learn SQLite & xml parsing for our project applications!
can anybody guide me about which books or data shall i refer for this?
Atleast please suggest some sites or ebooks!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

[IOS SDK: first advice for beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539990/ios-sdk-first-advice-for-beginners)