# How to insert data coming from web service into sql database in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am developing an app where I need to insert data coming from web service into sqlite3 database.Web service returns XML data with 5 tags.Now after XML parsing how to insert parsed data into sql database?
Can I code for this???
Thanks in advance..

Comment: This is far too broad a question to answer here.  I recommend reading some of the resources linked to in this question: [Add SQLite Database to iphone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487339/add-sqlite-database-to-iphone-app) and coming back when you have a specific question about an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

Inserting XML data in sqlite database is no different that inserting **any** data. So there are 3 parts of the problem you are trying to solve:

- Calling the web service and getting the data
- Parsing the data and populating some object
- Inserting that data in sqlite database which has columns as per your object structure

[NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) are the classed you need to look at for solving first 2 problems. Third one would be solved using [sqlite library](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html). Without more information about object structure it is difficult to suggest anything else. But you should find enough documentation on using sqlite if you search around.