# how fetch the data at same time when i register the all information on webserver in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have one xib and that xib i put on username, password, and one button is login

and in the tabbar i have one tab bar which name is registration if i tab the registration it will go to server bec i have given the server path bec all form are create in ther to take user information which means username, password firstname and lastname this is on registration form

and now if the user submit this form on server
then i have to show pop message which show that u are now register after that 
the login page should show which i show in xib in first line in there i have to fetch the data that data which the user created there username and password in server

this all fetch should hapen within the same time when the user submit the registertion form after that the login page should work but one condition is there suppose if the network is availble then the username and password should cheak wheather the same username and password  are have or not on web server if the network is not there then which the user put ther username and password  for login it should be match with the database table from local by using sqlite database in iphone

please help me friend in this how can i do this on same regitration and fetch the data with json and save in database localy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Touch up inside of your Login button can send a [Async/Sync request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704985/objective-c-asynchronous-web-request-with-cookies/1144254#1144254) to the server with entered user name and password. If you use Async then implement the NSURLdelegate methods.
2. Parse the response using [NSXML parser](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/UsingParser.html)
3. Once authenticated save the response in [local database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487339/add-sqlite-database-to-iphone-app/487531#487531)

Check the response for cases when network is not available and based on that take action in the handler for login button press.

Comment: friend i am not using the xml i am using the json for getin thedata from server

Comment: Well when you get the data parsing is in your control. May be you can write more on what is the request you send and what is sample response for better answers.