# Best Way to save array of objects in iPhone app.

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, saving-data, data-persistence

I have an iPhone program with a table view. The table view gets its data from a NSMutable Array. I want people to be able to add data to that table, i.e add objects to that array. Using `addObject` and `reloadData`, I am able to add objects to the array, and reload the table view so that the newly added data is also displayed. However, once I re-launch the app, the newly added data is missing. My question is what is the best way to store the array in the iPhone so that at re launch i can populate the table with the user added data?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think these are your options.

### 1) NSUserDefaults

If you just want to store a single array information you can use `NSUserDefaults` one of the easiest method of storing data.A good tutorial [here](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/).

> PS : Never [use NSUserDefault for saving sensitive](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/01/05/using-keychain-to-store-passwords-ios-iphone-ipad) information,
>   like login credentials. For that use [KeyChain services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html).A simple tutorial explaining the usage [here](http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code).

### 2) Core Data

If you have a large set of data and looking for a database style storage, then you should look at core data. Core data is a high level API written over lower SQLite concepts and is very good. A good tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started) and [here](http://www.bukisa.com/articles/180100_iphone-core-data-tutorial-part-1)

### 3) SQLite

If you want to use database using old fashioned way (writing queries) you can use sqlite directly on iPhone. You could get good information from [here](http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/), [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-sqlite-on-the-iphone) and from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487339/add-sqlite-database-to-iphone-app).

Comment: @Krishnabhadra I am using sqlite to store the array of data and I have more than one view controller in my application and my question is Is it right to create a singleton class to store that array in mutableform and get that information from any view controller.