# How to import and use the .db file in my application in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have a .db file taken from my android application, and now I need to use that .db file in my iphone application and access that database.

Can someone please suggest me how could I do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQLite database in an iPhone application. For information on how to incorporate it, please see the myriad solutions to this post: [Add an SQLite database to an iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487339/add-sqlite-database-to-iphone-app)