# Is it possible to use Android database for iphone application?

Tags: android, ios, database, sqlite

I am developing an content oriented app for android and iphone. I finished developing in android which has database in the format of androidApp.db. Is it possible to use the same database for iphone as well because in iphone the database format is .sqlite.

Is it possible to use **Android - androidAppdatabase.db**

for **iOS  - iphoneAppdatabase.sqlite**?.

If so please could you suggest some steps.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the db file is used to copy in both android and iPhone applications, check following link, to know how to do this in iOS.

[Add an SQLite database to an iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487339/add-an-sqlite-database-to-an-iphone-app)

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I tried to open the android.db in firebox sqlitemanager but i couldn't

Comment: you can open .db file as well. just select all files in file type.

Comment: yes.. i found that before seeing your comment. Thanks for your support.. +1 for your answer.. it helps

Answer (score 2):

**YES**, its is you can use this DB  it in both android as well as iOS

android and iOS both supports **SQLite**

**EDIT :** [Download](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/download.html) SQLite expert from here

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I am happy now if so could you suggest some steps please

Comment: I tried to open the android.db in firebox sqlitemanager but i couldn't.. thats what i asked steps because i am not sure what i am doing wrong